# Create User Account -- php makes HTML form disappear

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on building a PHP based Login/Create Account script. The form displays properly as long as the PHP at the top of the file is commented out/doesn't exist. As soon as I place the php in the file, the form disappears. Can anyone see if they find a reason as to why this is happening?

Thanks,
Matt

//edit 
So I discovered that the error resides with the if/else statement for checking that passwords match. If I comment out the else statement, the page displays properly, as soon as it is commented out, I get a blank page. I even commented out the mysql_query() and just put in a simple echo, no luck.

```
$db_found2 = conServer();

if($db_found2) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) || !empty($_POST['password']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['conpassword'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['username'];
        $conpassword = $_POST['conpassword'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if ($password != $conpassword) {
            $errormsg = "";
            $passerr = "Passwords do not match!";

        }
    }
}

function conServer() {
    $user_name = ""; //not displayed for privacy purposes
    $password = ""; //not displayed for privacy purposes
    $database = ""; //not displayed for privacy purposes
    $server = "localhost";
    $table = "users";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    return $db_found;
}


?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="login.css" />
</head>

<body class="login">
    <div id="login">

    <form id="loginform" action="create.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="username">
        Username *
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><span class="error"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></span>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password">
        Password *
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><span class="error"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></span>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password">
        Confirm Password *
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="conpassword" id="password"/><span class="error"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></span><span class="error"><?php echo $passerr; ?></span>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="email">
        Email *
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><span class="error"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></span>
        </label>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Go ->"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps you need to move the function to the top, before you call it? And you are missing a ";".

Comment: I originally had it outside of a function at the top and thought it could be causing the error so I placed it in a function.

Comment: I think the answers below are on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably an error in the script on top causing the script to terminate. If error reporting is off, all you get is a white page.

How to enable [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Also check for the [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting:

```
ini_get('display_errors');
```

Comment: I added those two lines to the top of my file, but I am still just getting a blank white page.

Answer (score 3):

Well at first glance the only thing I see and is trivial, a missing ';' at the end of the '$passerr = "Passwords do not match!"' line.
Please do some debugging, and share the result here.
I'm thinking on stuff like echoing the $db_found2 variable after calling the function and stuff, just to know where do you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried echoing the $db_found2 variable and nothing showed up. I am quite confused with this. I am just learning PHP, but created a successful script and I did everything the exact same way. Hmm..

Comment: From that I think your function has an error in it.
mysql_select_db() should return either true or false.
Continue debugging, maybe you use bad values for connecting.
Try this code with a DB u know for certain how to connect to.
Consider reading this page, has some valuable information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: I switched from using the function. Got it to work though. Not really sure what the error was. I just commented the whole thing out and then added an echo and uncommented line by line.

Comment: Great, always start with extensive debugging.
You should be able to give me credit for helping though. ^^